# Excel - Need to match pairs of value in rows

Tags: excel

I have just the following, long set. I need to know which category_name + event_name does not have also the program admin. I don't care if there is an admin but no leader only if there is a leader and then no admin following.
I am not sure how to check in the further rows for like value. Please note the program admin may not be following exactly the row after program leader.

```
category_name  event_name                       worker_role
-------------  ----------                       -----------
Activities     0- Behavior Management Training  Program Leader
Activities     0- Behavior Management Training  Program Admin
```

If the data was like this:

```
Activities     0- Behavior Management Training  Program Leader
Activities     1- Behavior Management Training  Program Leader
Activities     1- Behavior Management Training  Program Admin
```

Then I want an indication after Activies 0 because there is no program admin row with that code.

Comment: What is preventing you from even trying to accomplish this task?

Comment: What type of code is looking for this value in the speadsheet. I have tried lookup to no avail

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: I feel like you are looking for COUNTIFS

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for COUNTIFS.  Try this in column D:

```
=countifs(A:A, A2, B:B, B2, C:C, "Program Admin")
```

You will be counting the number of times that column A matches the value for the row, column B matches the value for the row and column C contains Program Admin.

See this Google Sheet.  The formulas work the same in Excel.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TPd9PvBoOaWX684EC2B_PnQ7Ng5T1057CSm-IB_9NSI/edit#gid=0